# IP Classes selection

Tags: networking, ip

Suppose I need 200 host in a network, and I´m sure that I won´t need more than that, the reasonable selection will be to choose a **class C** IP range for my network, but what if I choose a **class B** range for those 200 host, there will be  performance issues? or another inconveniences?

Comment: -1  you'd hopefully know if you googled, that classful addressing hasn't been done for decades, and it's basically cisco certification material(any others?), that continues to teach it.  If you mean /16 range vs /24 range then say that.

Comment: I just started to study a week ago...yeah it´s Cisco study material, thanks for nothing.

Comment: Actually you should appreciate being told that what you're learning is decades out of date, by me telling you that, you learn something you didn't know before(and you should've known from a simple google search). You're in a better position if you were to know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a larger Network should not lead to performance issues. Performance depends on the number of active hosts in the network and not on the address space provided for it, after all.

However, I would not recommend unnecessary large provisioning of subnets.
Since you are now pretty sure that you won't get more than 200 Host, just choose a /24 subnet. You have 55 host addresses as buffer, and you did not waste a lot of addresses that you could use for another subnet that you will possibly need in the future. If you still want to have a free buffer because it could be that you will need more than 255 hostaddresses I would do it like this:

- 192.168.0.0 /24 #workstation subnet
- 192.168.1.0 /24 #workstation buffer subnet
- 192.168.2.0 /24 #example subnet (e.g. printer subnet)

If you now have to expand your workstation subnet you just choose the free subnet that you set as buffer.
This has a few advantages:

If you don't need additional space for you workstation subnet you can use it for something else (e.g. Server). Also you don't have a very big broadcast domain (that has very much the potential to have an performance impact).

I hope I could help with this answer.

Comment: What does this answer add to mine and grawity's? I see a contraddiction between the statement "using a larger Network should not lead to performance issues" and "that has very much the potential to have an performance impact". Would you please clarify this concept better?

Comment: @simlev I explained that a little vague:  A largely provisioned subnet with few active hosts has no impact on performance. However, having a large provisioned network with a large amount of active hosts (which is the case is my example above) can cause performance issues because of the traffic that would occur with broadcast directed traffic.

To the question on what my post adds to yours and grawitys... Except maybe a few easy to understand practical examples, nothing much. I'm afraid I just didn't notice that similar answers already existed. But maybe it servers as a nice summery.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any performance problem with using a larger network. Talking generally and not just Class C vs Class B, people usually start with a smaller network, possibly leaving some unused space in case they want to expand it later. The reason is, they might later need to use other network spaces.

So the only problem I find with this is occupying network space you might later need. E.g. let's say you reserve 192.168.0.0/16 to you company's PCs. One day you introduce tablets as company assets and you want to assign them a separate network segment...you can't (in the 192.168.x.x range). You'll then need to reduce the PC network, possibly changing some already used IPs.

Common practice is start with a /24, or possibly two, three, depending on how many devices you foresee you might need to assign an ipv4 to. So e.g. you could start with 192.168.4.0/23 which is as large as two /24 and leaves plenty of space to grow it into e.g. 192.168.4/22 and one day add e.g. a 192.168.40.0/23 for tablets...

**Edit:** see @grawity's comment which explains this concept better and with fewer words.

Comment: It might be good to _reserve_ a larger space but only assign a smaller one (e.g. reserve /20's but assign 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.16.0/24, 192.16.32.0/24, and so on), that way you'll have space for growing old subnets _and_ setting up new ones.

Answer (score 2):

Performance problems mainly just depend on number of active hosts. It doesn't matter how large the address range is – 200 hosts in a /8 will work the same way as 200 hosts in a /24.

(Yes, /8, /16, and /24. *Please* stop measuring network sizes in classes.

And if /16 is too big and /24 is too small, then just use a /20 or something like that.)

---

I *think* the majority of issues in large broadcast domains is caused by

- hosts' ARP/ND caches filling up;
- excessive network traffic (broadcasts & multicasts) by "chatty" autodiscovery protocols such as NetBIOS or mDNS or UPnP.

Several decades ago, when Ethernet was still a shared medium and used hubs & such, more hosts would also have meant a greatly increased number of packet collisions, to the point of making the network nearly unusable. Shouldn't be an issue nowadays with switched Ethernet.

But either way, all of the above only depend on the number of *connected* systems, not on address assignments.

Comment: thanks for your answer....Cisco´s fault, see if you can convince them to change their training stuff, back to my question...so why bother with classes if I can simply use A class (/8) for whatever number of host I need..I need 20 host class A....I need 400 host use class A....need 10000 host use class A

Comment: @ThisNameWasTaken: Because you'll run out of addresses when you need to separate subnets for _other_ reasons, e.g. security or routing policies.

Comment: As for Cisco... even though they still talk about classes, I'm sure they _do_ include the concept of "subnetting" – subdividing a classful block into smaller ranges. Subnet masks have existed for many years before /x and CIDR.

Comment: Calm down man, I just started to study a week ago. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Usually a network uses *private ranges*:

10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255

172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255

192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255

These ranges are part of a standard published in [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918).

You can select **any range** from these and any **subnet mask**.  Keep in mind that class routing (class A, Class, class C) is a thing of the past. So you can mix and match, for example you can use `10.100.1.0` with mask `255.255.255.0` or `10.1.0.0`with mask `255.255.240.0`.

As it is your *private network* you won't be causing problems to other networks.

Your internet-connecting router will do a thing called [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation?oldformat=true) that translate your private addresses to a public address.

Why do you have to do all this?

Because you can't use public address inside your private network. Those public adddresses are assigned to public servers as Google, Yahoo, Facebook, etc. and you will cause a mess for them, for your router and your users.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the performance question at all though. And even if one talks about "class B" and "class C", that doesn't mean they're trying to use public addresses – e.g. 192.168.x.x was originally just a range of 256 class-C nets, and 10.x.x.x was a single class-A, regardless of any private-use reservations.